# PhpStorm warning for react attributes in jsx file with SCSS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm

How to remove "Unknown class name" warning in PhpStorm in jsx file?

Suppose I have a class in SCSS `tab-lists` with item like

```sass
.tab-lists {
      &__item {
        width: 1 / 3 * 100%;
        display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

and in my jsx file I use like this:

```
<Tab className={`${styles["tab-lists__item"]}`}>Overview</Tab>
```

but my PhpStorm always shows

> Unknown class name "tab-lists__item"

How to remove this warning?

Comment: Are you using React Css Modules plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11004-react-css-modules)?

Comment: yes! i am using this plugin

Answer (score 3):

The error message comes from the third-party [React Css Modules](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11004-react-css-modules) plugin, please report the issue to the plugin vendor (https://github.com/Kemoke/ReactCssModules/issues)

PhpStorm itself can resolve SASS/LESS selectors created with `&` since v. 2021.1, see [WEB-35215](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35215)